# Views with one exposed filter not returning all results?

Tags: views

I need a bit of help with a simple view I have: I created a custom content type, imported about 900+ nodes into it, set up a view with Input Required + Exposed Filter based on the title + Ajax. The Exposed filter uses "contains".

It's working for the most part but some of the nodes don't come up, i.e. if you search "eggs" nothing comes up. Here's the view http://www.ovwrc.com/waste-lookup and you can see that "Eggs" exists as a node. http://www.ovwrc.com/waste-lookup/organics-green-cart/eggs .

I don't have any filters on the view except for 1. Is Published, 2. Is content type "Trash".

I have the problem with other items but I can't figure out the pattern for the effected items in order to troubleshoot.

EDIT: Thanks to help below, we've isolated it to views not returning results if the "body" field is empty. This is where I'm stuck now.

Comment: If you go to (in this specific case anyway)`node/800/edit` what is showing in the Title field?

Comment: I renamed in "Title" to "Item" in the content type but it shows "Eggs": http://i.imgur.com/On3L3WV.png

Comment: Well something strange is certainly going on.  When you enter `eggs` you get no results, but also, when you enter `baz` you at least get a message saying no results found.  When you put in `foo` and `bar` you do get results, and they are formatted differently than the eggs node when you look at it directly.  So next step is a screen shot of the View UI page for this...

Comment: That, and/or what do the node edit pages for `Fast food containers (paper)` (the result of `foo`) and `Plastic barrels` (the result of `bar`) look like and do they obviously differ in any way from your `eggs`?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks something odd is going on! Here is my views UI: http://i.imgur.com/EhkAmom.png. The pages don't look different. I did a feeds import: Title(Item), Location (custom text field), and body. In views, I use PHP field to do an image replace based on the Location string.

Comment: check your php error logs: I bet your PHP is failing or doing something odd...and since it is via ajax, you are really seeing the WSoD which looks like nothing is being returned.

Comment: (the only other thing obviously different is `eggs` doesn't appear to have anything in its body whereby the `foo` and `bar` results do. Putting `e` in as an example shows lots of results all of which have content in the actual body of the node....)

Comment: Hm.. I think not having a body maybe the issue. All the results that are returned have body values. If you try "metal", you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yep, putting in `gg` finds Luggage and Toboggan :)  I'd add some content to the egg node body and see what happens.

Comment: I added "test" to "Cat Food" and it shows. Thanks for helping me isolate the issue! I didn't even know that this was an issue: no results if body is empty. Any ideas on how to disable that?

Comment: I've not seen Views hide results if a field being displayed doesn't exist or is empty but given that it didn't display "no results" I think it is failing in the ajax return somewhere; alas, we are getting far too detailed to figure out remotely :(

Comment: Even with Ajax turned off, I get the same results: http://www.ovwrc.com/waste-lookup?item=eggs. Hm.. Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: Quite welcome; you might want to look at `NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR` of that field and just put in something there to see if that changes things.

Comment: No Results Behaviour just has my one Global: Text field with the "Sorry, couldn't find that" text.

Comment: Right.  But you can select it specifically for the BODY field as well by just clicking on that field settings in the Views UI screen

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! I de-selected all the no result behaviour options in the BODY field and it still didn't work, but then I thought what if I just add a Global Text Field, hide the body field, and put all the fields int the Global Text Field? Well, it worked! Thanks again.